Blower motor failed on my car, same time as I got a parasitic draw from car stereo. Are these issues related?
2005 Scion tC.
Car stereo is a Boss Audio Systems BCPA9.
The blower motor stopped working completely, at the same time as the stereo screen kept staying on after taking the keys out of the ignition.
What's the connection?

To my knowledge, there's no connection. These two things should be on completely different circuits. The blower motor most likely runs through a resister which is tied to the switch. This draws a lot of juice and requires its own circuit. The radio should go through the BCM (or whatever Toyota calls the Body Control Module). It would be my approximation these two issues are not connected other than by coincidence.
